# How to get a directory path of resources during test runs?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cmake

I have a following structure of directories:

```
root
| - includes
| - src
| - test
    |- unit
    |- integration
    |- resources
```

and I was wondering how can I get a directory path in my tests (when they are being executed) of `test/resources` folder because I want to reference (load) something from that directory.

Resources are not built, they represent normal `xml` files.

The problem is that multiple people are building this project and some of them are building it in source and other ones outside, so the executable with test code (lets call it `TestRunner.exe`) will have a different running folder. This means the directory path isn't changed during the test run, but that still doesn't mean we can statically reference it like `../resources` which would mean our `TestRunner.exe` is located in the `test/build` folder because someone can build this project somewhere else.

Comment: Is there anything that stops you from using [absolute](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/absolute-path-vs-relative-path-linuxunix/) file paths?

Comment: @Leif_Lundberg Yes, this tests should be able to run on also windows.

Comment: Which of these directories (if any) contain a CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: @squareskittles Dirs that contain `CMakeLists.txt` files are `root`, `src` and `test`.

Comment: When you say "*I was wondering how can I get a directory path*"... when do you want to access this path? When the TestRunner executable is building? When the TestRunner executable is running? It is unclear how you intend to use the resources path. Does the resources path ever change? Are the resources built as well, and thus, may be built in- or out-of-source?

Comment: @squareskittles I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

In the CMakeLists.txt files under unit/ and integration/ you may define a variable like this:

```
set(RESOURCES_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../resources")
get_filename_component(RESOURCES_ABS_PATH ${RESOURCES_PATH} ABSOLUTE)
```

You may use one of those variables to pass an argument to your tests, or define an environment variable, or a compile symbol or [build a configuration file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) header.

See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html